# ADMOB free reward anuncio video premiado não funciona

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, admob

Estou com um problema na exibição de anúncios do tipo video do admob free, tenho outros tipos de anuncio e funciona 100%.
Sei que tem algumas versões mais atuais do admob free, mas gostaria de resolver sem  ter que atualizar, pois impacta em outras coisas.
O mais curioso no meu código é que ao invés de abrir o anúncio de vídeo abre o anuncio do tipo intercistial, isso quando eu coloco o id = '', se coloco o id do anuncio que criei no admob, ele da erro rewardVideoLoadFail, entra nesse evento.

utilizo cordova-android 6.2.3
e sobre a verão do plugin:

```
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.5.0",        
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.8.0",
    "cordova-android": "6.2.3",        
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.10.0",
```

Meu método para abrir o anuncio de video:

```
showRewardVideo(rewardFn?): Promise<boolean> {

  const rewardVideoConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
    id: '', //test    
    isTesting: true,
    autoShow: true
  }

  let loadingContent: string;
  loadingContent = 'Carregando Vídeo';
  const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'bubbles',
    content: loadingContent
  });
  loading.present();

  this.admobFree.rewardVideo.config(rewardVideoConfig);
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {

    rewardVideoClose = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_CLOSE).subscribe(() => {
      rewardVideoLoad.unsubscribe();
      rewardVideoLoadFail.unsubscribe();
      rewardVideoClose.unsubscribe();
      rewardVideoReward.unsubscribe();
    });
    rewardVideoLoad = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_LOAD).subscribe(() => {
      this.admobFree.rewardVideo.show()
        .then(() => {
          loading.dismiss();
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          loading.dismiss();
          resolve(false);
        });
    });

    rewardVideoLoadFail = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_LOAD_FAIL).subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('rewardVideoLoadFail', value);
      loading.dismiss();
      resolve(false);
    });
    rewardVideoReward = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_REWARD).subscribe(() => {
      rewardFn();
      rewardVideoReward.unsubscribe();
    });

    this.admobFree.rewardVideo.prepare()
      .then(() => { })
      .catch(() => {
        loading.dismiss();
        resolve(false);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes e de muito procurar por esse problema, consegui resolver.
Utilizando o tipo de anuncio vídeo premiado como teste nem sempre tem um vídeo para ser exibido pela admob, sei que em outras versões para funcionar basta tirar o numero do id do admb e colocar em branco e o vídeo de teste aparece, porém no meu caso com as versões que utilizo não funcionou. Tirei a opção de test coloquei como false. Mesmo assim ao compilar não funciona, mas compilando em --prod --release e preparar o apk como se fosse publicar o vídeo abre corretamente e todos os eventos funcionam.